# How do I explain this behavior of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, asynchronous, responsive-design

I have a piece of code

```
           var wsr = $('#work-sample-row');
            for (var i = 0, n = newRows.length; i < n; ++i)
            {
                var thisBox = box.clone();
                var thisNewRow = newRows[i];
                thisBox.find('.work-item-preview-outer').css('background-image', 'url(' + thisNewRow['imageurl'] + ')');
                thisBox.find('.work-title').text(thisNewRow['title']);
                thisBox.find('.work-descr-short').text(thisNewRow['sumsmall']);
                thisBox.find('.work-link-wrap').attr('href', siteUrl + '/our-work/ ' + workUrlPiece + '?id=' + thisNewRow['id']);
                wsr.append(thisBox); 
                setTimeout(function(){thisBox.css('opacity','1');}, i * 300);
            }
```

for adding `n` children to a `div` and animating their appearance by having the `opacity` appear (along with CSS3 `transition`) with 300 ms in between each one beginning to appear. But for some reason, it was only working for the very last one that was added. So instead I changed the end of of the code to

```
                //setTimeout(function(){thisBox.css('opacity','1');}, i * 300);
            }     
            k = 1;
            wsr.children().each(function(){
                var that = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){that.css('opacity','1');}, (k++) * 300);
            });
```

and that worked, but of course that's inelegant because I each to iterate through the elements again. How can I make the first way work?

Comment: what is `box`  and `newRows`? Show us how these are defined.

Comment: @DelightedD0D `box` is `$('<div class="mb-30-for-mobile col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 work-column" style="opacity:0;"><a class="work-link-wrap"><div class="work-item-preview-outer"><div class="work-item-preview-inner"><h3 class="work-title"></h3><p class="work-descr-short"></p></div></div></a></div>');` and  `newRows` is JSON from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when the `setTimeout` callbacks are executed the `thisBox` variable refers to the last cloned object. JavaScript (not ECMAScript 2015) doesn't support the block scope feature.

You can use an immediately-invoked function which similar to your `each` callback creates a new scope.

```
 for (var i = 0, n = newRows.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var thisBox = box.clone();
    // ...
    (function(box, index) {
        setTimeout(function(){ box.css('opacity','1');}, index * 300);
    })(thisBox, i);
 }
```

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes, the point is having a function that _remembers_ the passed/defined values.